# Error in returning java object to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring

I am returning a java object to client(javascript) page, i.e. converting java object to JSON object but am facing no converter found for return value error.
I have added all spring jars and jackson-all-xxx.jar.
The below is the method that gets called from a html page using **$http.get('url').**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/springAngularJS",method=RequestMethod.GET)               
public @ResponseBody Person  getPerson() {  
System.out.println("111111111");  
Person person = new Person();
    person.setFirstName("Java");
    person.setLastName("Honk");
    return person;
    }
```

My html page: (posting only JS part)
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

```
function MyController($scope, $http){

    $scope.getPersonDataFromServer = function() {           
        $http.get("springAngularJS").
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.person = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          // called asynchronously if an error occurs
          // or server returns response with an error status.
        });

    };
};
```

Any help to resolve this would be appreciated..
I am a beginner..:)

Comment: Where's the JSON object you're talking about?

Comment: Are you using spring boot if not how are building your project ?

Comment: @Shahbour.. again a new term Spring boot :), No am using eclipse, have added all required jars into it and trying to run this simple application.

Comment: I suggest on you to use spring boot with maven, it should handle all your dependency better

Comment: @Shahbour thanks for the suggestion. For the time being am trying to learn core concepts n all. It would be great if you could put something to solve the issue am facing.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with project dependency and not code , as the above code is correct .

Again I suggest on you to start with Spring-boot it will allow you to concentrate on the code only  [working example](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/)